# MongoDB Aggregation Projection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

If I have a collection as follows:

```
db.cafe.insert({name: "Cafe1", customers: [{name: "David", foods: [{name : "cheese"}, {name: "beef"}]}, {name: "Bill", foods: [{name: "fish"}]} ]})


    db.cafe.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54f5ae58baed23b7a34fccb6"),
    "name" : "Cafe1",
    "customers" : [
        {
            "name" : "David",
            "foods" : [
                {
                    "name" : "cheese"
                },
                {
                    "name" : "beef"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name" : "Bill",
            "foods" : [
                {
                    "name" : "fish"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I extract an array containing just the food objects for people called "David".
Desired output is just the array of foods, i.e:

```
[{name: "cheese"}, {name: "beef"}]
```

I have tried an aggregation pipeline that unwinds the cafes customers, then matches on name then projects the food, e.g:

```
db.cafe.aggregate( [{$unwind : "$customers"}, {$match : {"customers.name": "David"}}, {$project : {"customers.foods": 1, _id : 0} 

}] ).pretty()
{
    "customers" : {
        "foods" : [
            {
                "name" : "cheese"
            },
            {
                "name" : "beef"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

This seems close to the desired result, however, I'm left with the issue that the foods I want are referenced as an array under the property customers.foods. I would like the result to directly be:

```
[
            {
                "name" : "cheese"
            },
            {
                "name" : "beef"
            }
        ]
```

is there a way I can achieve the desired output?

Comment: I think you should change your project as below
`{"$project":{"_id":0,"food":"$customers.foods"}}`

Answer (score 3):

You are doing your projection wrong.

```js
db.cafe.aggregate( [
    { "$match" : { "customers.name": "David" }},
    { "$unwind" : "$customers" }, 

    { "$project" : { "foods": "$customers.foods", "_id": 0 }}
])
```

**Output**

```js
{ "foods" : [ { "name" : "cheese" }, { "name" : "beef" } ] }
```

Comment: Thanks, this is close but not quite what I was after. The trouble I have got is in my server-side code I am using an Object Mapper to convert to/from bson to my Java objects. I was trying to avoid creating another object dedicated to this result set and reuse an existing one. But it seems like it's not possible. Thanks for the suggestion though, it was certainly close.

Answer (score 1):

You can also get (something very, very close to) your desired output with a regular query:

```
> db.cafe.find({ "customers.name" : "David" }, { "customers.$.foods" : 1, "_id" : 0 })
{ "customers" : [ { "name" : "David", "foods" : [ { "name" : "cheese" }, { "name" : "beef" } ] } ] }
```

Customers will be an array containing just the first object with `name : "David"`. You should prefer this approach to the aggregation as it's vastly more performant. You can extract the `foods` array in client code.

Comment: So what would be the point of notating as "customers.$.foods" when that does not actually just select the field as asked? That is like saying "don't bother projecting fields because you can just remove the ones you don't want in client code". I don't see how that provides any value.

Comment: Thanks. I think for my actual use case I will need the aggregation pipeline (because I'm filtering an array with various criteria as well as applying sorting and limiting) as it's not actually as straight forward as this question suggests. I was using a simplified version of the problem I was facing.